# Is Moksha compulsorily given to every died people by their family?

Tags: vedas, moksha

What is death and rebirth cycle according to Veda ? After giving Moksha, can that soul take rebirth ?

Comment: Moksha means mukti, mukti(liberation/freedom) from cycle of rebirth.